# ¿Cómo recorro este arreglo indexado?

Tags: javascript, php, html, poo, mvc

Estoy trabajando con PHP puro. Estoy utilizando MVC con POO y tengo un método que me permite obtener los datos de una tabla mysql, pero cuando trato de recorrerlo, no sé como hacerlo.

Este es el método almacenado en el Modelo

```
public function getAll(){
    $items = [];

    try {
        $query = $this->query('SELECT * FROM services');
        while ($p = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $item = new servicesModel();
            $item->setCode($p['code']);
            $item->setName($p['name']);
            $item->setDescription($p['description']);
            $item->setPrice($p['price']);
            array_push($items, $item);
        }

        return $items;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log('SERVICEMODEL:getAll -> PDOException ' . $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya sabes cómo queda la respuesta de tu método? Lo suyo es recorrer ese array, puedes usar un foreach mismamente

Comment: *pero cuando trato de recorrerlo en la vista, no sé como hacerlo* De entrada hay un problema de enfoque. La vista debería servir para presentar los datos, no tienes que recorrer nada en la vista, toda esa lógica debería ir en el modelo (imagina que tienes mil modelos, ¿pondrás mil métodos en la vista?). Supongamos que necesitas una tabla (HTML) en algunos casos, podrías poner en el modelo un método llamado `showTable` donde construyes tu tabla y la retornas. Supongamos que quieres esos mismos datos, pero en un json, pues creas otro método `showJson` en el modelo y usas la vista para mostrarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Perdón, me equivoqué, de hecho en el mismo modelo tengo el método para recorrer el arreglo, pero como soy bastante nuevo en programación, no sé cómo hacerlo. Eso es lo que me retorna un var_dump del método que contiene los datos:
array(1) { [0]=> object(ServicesModel)#13 (5) { ["code":"ServicesModel":private]=> string(1) "2" ["name":"ServicesModel":private]=> string(9) "Cathering" ["description":"ServicesModel":private]=> string(38) "Servicio de Cathering para tus eventos" ["price":"ServicesModel":private]=> string(6) "250000" ["db"]=> object(Database)#14 (0) { } } }

Comment: @Jakala
Esto es lo que me retorna var_dump del arreglo que contiene los datos:
array(1) { [0]=> object(ServicesModel)#13 (5) { ["code":"ServicesModel":private]=> string(1) "2" ["name":"ServicesModel":private]=> string(9) "Cathering" ["description":"ServicesModel":private]=> string(38) "Servicio de Cathering para tus eventos" ["price":"ServicesModel":private]=> string(6) "250000" ["db"]=> object(Database)#14 (0) { } } }

Comment: Si no organizas bien tu contexto MVC pronto te encontrarás perdido, y mezclando cosas que no tienes que mezclar. Es tan simple como esto: **desde el controlador**, aplicando lo dicho en mi anterior comentario, harias esto cuando quieras mostrar un HTML: `$vista->printHtml($modelo->showHtml($parametros));` y cuando necesites un json, harías esto: `$vista->printJson($modelo->showJson($parametros));` Así, tu vista tendrá métodos **para imprimir cualquier contenido** poniendo solamente las cabeceras adecuadas cuando éstas sean requeridas, y en el modelo implementas la lógica del tipo de contenido.

Comment: Para este caso es fundamental que nos muestres cómo conectas las tres partes: Controlador, Modelo y Vista. Sospecho que tienes el código mal organizado, y de ahí tu problema o duda para algo tan simple como mostrar unos datos. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega cómo llamas al Modelo desde el Controlador y cómo intentas pasar los datos a la Vista. Muestra también qué métodos tienes en la Vista.

Comment: Prueba cambiar query por -> **mysql_fetch_array** devuelve la fila actual y mueve el puntero de datos hacia adelante a la fila siguiente. Cuando se recorren todas las filas, devuelve false y el bucle while termina

Comment: @Caldeiro `mysql_fetch_array` es una función de `mysqli` y OP está usando PDO, son dos cosas distintas. Tratándose de un contexto MVC, el peor error aquí es que OP está queriendo trasladar lógica propia del Modelo a la Vista y esto le traerá muchos, pero muchos problemas. OP debe construir su tabla en el modelo y devolverla para que la misma sea mostrada en la vista.

Comment: Solo para descartar... el metodo `fetch` de `PDO` devuelve un `pop` de una pila? (sobre el resultado de la ejecucion de la consulta), ya que pues parece funcionar como una pila, pense que `fetch` solo retornaba el primer valor ya que lo habia llegado a usar anteriormente, pero a pesar de que la consulta podia tener multiples resultados solo me arrojaba el primero, quizas es porque nunca llegue a ejecutarlo multiples veces con un while y hace poco fue que comence a usar `mysqli` (porque en la empresa en la que estoy se usa).

Comment: Entonces `PDO` tambien devuelve pilas?, porque pense que siempre devolvia arrays, pero me topo con la sorpresa que el `fetch` es como el equivalente de `mysqli_fetch_array` por ejemplo. Ya que segun tengo entendido al `OP` ese codigo le ha funcionado. En mi caso yo siempre llegue a usar `fetchAll` para `PDO`, ya que asi no tenia que reasignar informacion en otro array si queria reutilizarla y ademas me devolvia directamente todos los resultados en una array asociativo, listo para recorrerlos.

Comment: Cuidado, el MVC nació antes que PHP, en un contexto de aplicaciones síncronas. MVC en un contexto web tiene [diferentes enfoques](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo%E2%80%93vista%E2%80%93controlador#Uso_en_aplicaciones_Web), sobre todo en cuanto a la interacción entre V y C. El modelo debe ser tan agnóstico de la vista como para alejarse del HTML y acercarse a datos/estructuras/tipos nativos del lenguaje. Un modelo puede ser algo tan simple como un arreglo -incluso envuelto en una clase- y podrías [iterar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.iterations.php) para recorrerlo.

Comment: PDO no devuelve ni una pila ni una cola, puede devolver un arreglo; pero la estructura interna realmente es un [cursor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(base_de_datos)).

Comment: @Riven, como bien dice @Sal, cuando llamas a `query()` o a `execute()` recibes un cursor, representando en el contexto PDO por [la clase `PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php), la cual tiene varios métodos, entre ellos `fetch`  y `fetchAll` para obtener los datos que se hayan obtenido en la consulta ejecutada. `fetch` por decirlo en lenguaje coloquial, mueve ese cursor, o sea, en cada llamada a `fetch` el cursor se mueve una fila, mientras que `fetchAll` vuelca el cursor completo (todos los datos obtenidos) de golpe.

Comment: @Caldeiro
Muchas gracias por la ayuda amigo. Tomé el consejo de crear la tabla en el mismo modelo y mostrarla en la vista. Además de que cambié toda la función (soy nuevo y así la hacían en un video, pero viéndolo bien, él estaba haciendo algo distinto). Simplemente luego del fetch, ingresé todo a un arreglo y listo, con un for llamaba al valor de cada campo de cada item del arreglo asociativo y lo ingresaba en un td.

Answer (score 0):

**Así solucioné**

```
public function getAll(){
        $services = [];
        try {
            $query = $this->query('SELECT * FROM services');
            while($p = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $services[] = $p;
            }

            for($i=0;$i<count($services);$i++){
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>" . $services[$i]['name'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $services[$i]['description'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $services[$i]['price'] . "</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
            }
            
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('SERVICEMODEL:getAll -> PDOException ' . $e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Meter esto en un modelo es una violación al principio de [separación de intereses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separaci%C3%B3n_de_intereses).

Comment: @sal
¿Qué me aconsejas entonces?, ¿retornar la consulta y recorrerlo en la vista desde un arreglo?

Comment: ¡¡ Exacto !!  :)